# Remove XML tags with specific values (as mask) using Notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have the below entries in my XML file. I want to remove (find and replace with nothing) all and whole Song elements where FilePath starts with "D:\Sync\DJ\TBP". I want to keep the ones starting with "D:\Sync\DJ\Library2". I am unable to construct the Regular Expression, can you please help?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR9q5.png)

```
<Song FilePath="D:\Sync\DJ\Library2\Caribou - Julia Brightly.mp3" FileSize="5021908" Flag="25165826">
  <Tags Genre="Melodic" Album="Our Love" TrackNumber="7" Grouping="4" Year="2014" User1="T/" User2="v" Bpm="0.428571" Key="Am" Flag="1" />
  <Infos SongLength="121.986032" LastModified="1652480858" FirstSeen="1643922546" FirstPlay="1645175276" LastPlay="1648048342" PlayCount="6" Bitrate="320" UserColor="4278255615" Cover="1" />
  <Comment>Fade in/out! E3|vmkhb|32b+E3|vmkhb|16b</Comment>
 </Song>                                                                                                          
 <Song FilePath="D:\Sync\DJ\TBP\Avoure - Floyd (Original Mix).mp3" FileSize="13587852" Flag="1">
  <Tags Remix="Original Mix" Flag="2" />
  <Infos SongLength="339.6270" LastModified="1649571402" FirstSeen="1643899220" />
 </Song>
```

Comment: can you share some regex you tried?

Comment: I am very bad in RegEx, I tried:
[\t ]*<Song FilePath="D:\Sync\DJ\TBP\[0-9A-Z:-]*</song>
and
<Song FilePath="D:\Sync\DJ\TBP\[0-9A-Z:-]*</song>

Comment: most likely you are suffering regex matching too much content (`.*`), and thus replacing too much. have you tried using the `?` qualifier? (`.*?`) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching

Comment: No, I get an error: "Can't find the text". I am using the latest Notepad++

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: you propably have to escape the backslashes :) `D:\\Sync\\DJ\\TBP`

Answer (score 0):

This worked, thanks a lot

```js
[\t ]*<Song FilePath="D:\\Sync\\DJ\\TBP\\.*?</song>
```